# Rights on file read write execute

Tags: macos, terminal

I am logged in as "myuser" which is also the administrator of the computer. 
I have a file on which I have the following rights:

```
-r--r--r--   1 myuser  staff  167 17 Feb 14:26 my_python.py
```

However, when I type in `python my_python.py` on the command line, I still can run the file. Don't I need execute (x) rights in order to do that?!

The only way I cannot run the file is when I change the rights to:

```
----------   1 myuser  staff  167 17 Feb 14:26 my_python.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python only requires the file contents to be read.

Recall that Python is an interpreted language and just processes the contents of that file, rather than executing it; python is the executable here!
Therefore, calling the interpreter with the file as input/argument does not require other than read permissions (e.g.,`python example.py`).

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to be executable, because you are running the `python` executable and pass this file to it.

However if You'd like to execute this file with `./my_python.py` this file would have to be executable and has `#!/usr/bin/python` in the first line (or even better `#!/usr/bin/env python`).

Comment: why would that need to be executable if I try `./my_python.py`? `./`  only means I am in another folder to execute this file..

Comment: You can change `./` to the path to your py file. When You make it executable `chmod  +x` you won't have to execute `python` because it's going to be run automatically from `#!/usr/bin/python` line ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) )

Comment: Hm, that is still not clear. When I have the `rw` rights on a `.py` file and I execute it like `python whatever.py` I can. But, when I try to run `./python whaterever.py` that does not? Why do I need `x` rights to run that?!

Comment: Because `python` is not located in the current directory (it's probably in `/usr/bin/python` ). If You set `x` on the file it can be run without launching the `python` first (it does not have to be passed to python executable). So when the file has `x` you can simply run it by `/path/to/file.py` or if it's in the current dir with `./file.py` (remember about shebang).

Comment: @Stophface- `./` means the `current working directory`. So, `./python whatever.py` is telling the shell to look for `python` is the `current working directory`. I suggest you read `man execve` to understand what Mateusz Szolsek is talking about.